# Although my wamp server is installed in C: drive and i am installing my laravel project in my I: drive Is this right to successfully deploy my project

Tags: php, laravel, resources, wamp

i am new in web devloping this concern rises that my wamp server is install in my C: drive. And now i am installed my laravel project in my I: drive. Although my project is run successfully but problem is that when i want to fetch some assets like images,or any other templete using src or link=`{{url('public/assets/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css')}}` that is available in my public/assets/ directory but i am unable to fetch that data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glMK7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihH8f.png)

Comment: In wamp, create a `virtualhost` and then you are good to go.

Comment: please no images of code

Comment: [THE NEED for VIRTUAL HOSTS](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) On the WAMPServer site

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.